# Matrix of zeroes and ones without numpy

Tags: python, matrix

How would I create a matrix of single zeroes and ones in a size I specify **without numpy**? I tried looking this up but I only found results using it. I guess it would be using loops? Unless there's a more simple method?

For example, the size I specify could be 3 and the grid would be 3x3.

```
      Col 0    Col 1    Col 2
Row 0   0        1        0
Row 1   0        0        1
Row 2   1        1        1
```

Comment: What type would you like the matrix to be, a list of lists? Which entires should be 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
def m(s):
  return [s*[0] for _ in xrange(s)]
```

Comment: This will create multiple references to the same list, leading to errors.  The array will be three copies of one row and you won't be able to set values in the rows separately.

Comment: +1 - realized that after both of our edits, our answers are basically the same and yours was first :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured something out in the end that worked out better for my needs!